# How do I set CHARACTER SET and COLLATE SET on tables on Workbench ERP?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench, collation

I'm using school server, so we can't add new databases, we only use existing one, but we can add tables on that.

I want to use Danish character set with collation Danish, so that when ordering names they retrieved based on Danish alphabet.

How can I do this in Workbench ERP?

About the database server I use:
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.5.8-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

I did alter the table using this:

```
ALTER TABLE Users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_danish_ci;
```

This works.

**But how can I set it on Workbench ERP so that I don't have to update all tables every time after doing forward engineering?**

I try to change every table:
[image]

But the collation returns back to utf8_bin even if I save.

And what's explained in this vide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DflA8G5OCtQ&ab_channel=TechBrothersIT

There's no default_collation variable in my case.

I tried this on PHP too:

```
$this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8' SET COLLATION 'utf8_danish_ci'"));
```

But then I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET COLLATION 'utf8_danish_ci' at line 1
```

**How can I set charset and collation on Workbench ERP or PDO so that I don't have to update all tables every time after doing forward engineering?**

Comment: I am a little confused. I didn't think that "MySQL Workbench" worked with mariaDB databses. Maybe that is your issue!

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Any MySQL client should be able to connect to a MariaDB server. They have compatible protocols, at least in current versions.

Comment: Hi @BillKarwin I get a warning about some features not working when trying to connect MySQL Workbench to a mariaDB engine. Only a warning, but, am I taking it too seriously?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's true that MySQL and MariaDB both have some features the other does not, and the divergence is increasing gradually since MariaDB forked in 2010. Some SQL queries won't behave the same, some builtin functions are different, etc. But the protocol is the same. If you restrict yourself to basic queries it should be fine. But clearly MySQL Workbench can at least connect to MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin strangley, today, I installed DBeaver so I could get to both from one tool, probably didn't need to bother :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-names/

The syntax should be:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_danish_ci'
```